stroke width causes values to go over the zero line
I have made a bar chart which have two columns per category. These columns can have positive or negative values. My data values would sometimes have extremely large and small range or gap which results to small values not being visible enough. I have added a strokeWidth that extremely small values will have a minimum pixel and would still be visible in the graph.
After adding the strokeWidth, it messes with the columns axis starting position from the zero line. Negative items now displays above the zero line when it should be starting from there.

I think it is related to this: https://github.com/vega/vega/pull/3487
Try setting an offset on your y2:

{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
  "width": 700,
  "height": 370,
  "autosize": {"type": "fit", "contains": "padding"},
  "padding": {"bottom": 2, "right": 9, "left": 5},
  "config": {
    "axis": {
      "labelFont": "HelveticaNeueLTW01-55Roman",
      "titleFont": "HelveticaNeueLTW01-55Roman"
    }
  },
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "capital_flows",
      "values": [
        {"label": "2012", "capital_inflow": 208.91, "capital_outflow": -500},
        {"label": "2013", "capital_inflow": 115.61, "capital_outflow": -458.76},
        {"label": "2014", "capital_inflow": 135.7, "capital_outflow": -335.23},
        {"label": "2015", "capital_inflow": 148.75, "capital_outflow": -83.61},
        {"label": "2016", "capital_inflow": 152.57, "capital_outflow": 0.36},
        {"label": "2017", "capital_inflow": 198.23, "capital_outflow": 0.29},
        {"label": "2018", "capital_inflow": 911.81, "capital_outflow": 0.58},
        {"label": "2019", "capital_inflow": 5342.44, "capital_outflow": 14.48},
        {"label": "2020", "capital_inflow": 4664.46, "capital_outflow": 11.51},
        {"label": "2021", "capital_inflow": 3800.92, "capital_outflow": 7.54},
        {"label": "2022", "capital_inflow": 6633, "capital_outflow": 12.04},
        {"label": "2023", "capital_inflow": 7381.93, "capital_outflow": 5.31},
        {"label": "2024", "capital_inflow": 3612.31, "capital_outflow": 3.7}
      ],
      "transform": [
        {"type": "formula", "expr": "split(datum.label, ' ')", "as": "label"}
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "parsed",
      "source": ["capital_flows"],
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "aggregate",
          "fields": [
            "capital_inflow",
            "capital_inflow",
            "capital_outflow",
            "capital_outflow"
          ],
          "ops": ["min", "max", "min", "max"],
          "as": ["min_value1", "max_value1", "min_value2", "max_value2"]
        },
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "expr": "datum.max_value1 == 0 && datum.max_value2 == 0 ? 1 : datum.max_value1 > datum.max_value2 ? abs(datum.max_value1) : abs(datum.max_value2)",
          "as": "mergedMax"
        },
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "expr": "datum.min_value1 == 0 && datum.min_value2 == 0 ? -1 : datum.min_value1 < datum.min_value2 ? abs(datum.min_value1) : abs(datum.min_value2)",
          "as": "mergedMin"
        },
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "expr": "datum.mergedMax > datum.mergedMin ? datum.mergedMax : datum.mergedMin",
          "as": "max"
        },
        {"type": "formula", "expr": "-(datum.max)", "as": "min"}
      ]
    }
  ],
  "scales": [
    {
      "name": "x",
      "type": "band",
      "range": "width",
      "domain": {"data": "capital_flows", "field": "label"}
    },
    {
      "name": "y",
      "type": "linear",
      "range": "height",
      "nice": true,
      "zero": false,
      "domain": {"data": "parsed", "field": "limit"},
      "domainMin": {"signal": "pluck(data('parsed'), 'min')"},
      "domainMax": {"signal": "pluck(data('parsed'), 'max')"}
    }
  ],
  "axes": [
    {
      "orient": "bottom",
      "scale": "x",
      "zindex": 1,
      "labelFontSize": 12,
      "labelColor": "#85868C",
      "labelAlign": "center",
      "labelLineHeight": 16.8,
      "labelFontWeight": "normal",
      "labelPadding": 8,
      "labelOpacity": 1,
      "domain": false,
      "domainColor": "#e5e5e5",
      "domainWidth": 1,
      "ticks": false
    },
    {
      "orient": "left",
      "scale": "y",
      "zindex": 0,
      "labelFontSize": 12,
      "labelColor": "#85868C",
      "labelLineHeight": 16.8,
      "labelFontWeight": "normal",
      "labelPadding": 8,
      "labelOpacity": 1,
      "domain": false,
      "domainColor": "#e5e5e5",
      "grid": true,
      "gridOpacity": 0.5,
      "ticks": false,
      "tickCount": {"signal": "pluck(data('parsed'), 'max') < 1000 ? 4 : 6"},
      "gridDash": {"signal": "datum.value == 0 ? [0,0] : [4,4]"},
      "encode": {
        "labels": {
          "update": {
            "text": {
              "signal": "if(abs(datum.value) >= 1e9, format(datum.value/1e9, '$,.1~f') + 'B', if(abs(datum.value) >= 1e6, format(datum.value/1e6, '$,.1~f') + 'M', if(abs(datum.value) >= 1e3, format(datum.value/1e3, '$,.1~f') + 'K', format(datum.value, '$,.2~f'))))"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "marks": [
    {
      "name": "inflow",
      "type": "rect",
      "from": {"data": "capital_flows"},
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "xc": {"scale": "x", "field": "label", "band": 0.5},
          "width": {"value": 16},
          "y": {"scale": "y", "field": "capital_inflow"},
          "y2": {"scale": "y", "value": 0},
          "fill": {"value": "#68c487"},
          "cornerRadiusTopLeft": {
            "signal": "datum.capital_inflow > 0 ? '1' : '0'"
          },
          "cornerRadiusTopRight": {
            "signal": "datum.capital_inflow > 0 ? '1' : '0'"
          },
          "cornerRadiusBottomLeft": {
            "signal": "datum.capital_inflow > 0 ? '0' : '1'"
          },
          "cornerRadiusBottomRight": {
            "signal": "datum.capital_inflow > 0 ? '0' : '1'"
          },
          "stroke": {"signal": "datum.capital_inflow !== 0 ? '#68c487': null"}
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "outflow",
      "type": "rect",
      "from": {"data": "capital_flows"},
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "xc": {"scale": "x", "field": "label", "band": 0.5, "offset": 19},
          "width": {"value": 16},
          "y": {"scale": "y", "field": "capital_outflow"},
          "y2": {"scale": "y", "value": 0, "offset":1.5},
          "fill": {"value": "#FFB066"},
          "cornerRadiusTopLeft": {
            "signal": "datum.capital_outflow > 0 ? '1' : '0'"
          },
          "cornerRadiusTopRight": {
            "signal": "datum.capital_outflow > 0 ? '1' : '0'"
          },
          "cornerRadiusBottomLeft": {
            "signal": "datum.capital_outflow > 0 ? '0' : '1'"
          },
          "cornerRadiusBottomRight": {
            "signal": "datum.capital_outflow > 0 ? '0' : '1'"
          },
          "stroke": {"signal": "datum.capital_outflow !== 0 ? '#FFB066': null"},
          "strokeWidth": {"value": 1.5}
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}


Thanks @davidebacci :) the above works perfectly for large values but I noticed that negative values that are too small (-0.01 to -0.09 still displays above the zero line, does it need a different offset? Nothing seems to work for me while playing around with the offset value at the moment

The values are probably wrapping round. You might need to set a clamp on them

Sorry, not sure I get what you meant by "clamp" ? What I currently did in y2 was
"offset": {"signal": "datum.capital_outflow < 0 ? 1.5: 0"} but does not seem to work for column/bar with very small height. I can't depend on data values as it varies so, I wanted to check the pixel height of a column/bar, can that be accessed?

The pixel dimensions are in the bounds column I think.

If you have a reproducible example, ask a new question and we can take a look
